# Copying text using selenium send_keys in python

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to copy text using selenium python commands but for some reason it doesn't seem to work

Here is my code:

```
driver.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/') #opens the website
emailID = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mail"]') #find the email ID
ActionChains = ActionChains(driver)
ActionChains.double_click(emailID).perform()
ActionChains.send_keys(keys.CONTROL + 'c').perform()
```

Instead of:

```
ActionChains.send_keys(keys.CONTROL + 'c').perform()
```

I have also tried:

```
emailID.send_keys(keys.CONTROL + 'c')
```

But seem to constantly be getting this error:

```
module 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys' has no attribute 'CONTROL'
```

**EDIT:**

```
driver.get('https://google.com ') #opens the website
input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
ActionChains.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v').perform()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shadow/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/Test.py", line 28, in <module>
    ActionChains.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v').perform()
  File "C:\Users\Shadow\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\action_chains.py", line 336, in send_keys
    if self._driver.w3c:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_driver'
```

Comment: try `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`
`Keys.CONTROL + 'c'`
Don't forget the letter case

Comment: Should be posting a full working example. I believe it should `keys.Keys.CONTROL`.

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys fixed the issue. However, even though the code runs and there are no errors it seems to not be copying the text for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you just use `text`?

```
emailID = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mail"]')
text_emailID = emailID.text
print(text_emailID)
```

### Update

It seems to be hidden in the JS... so just use the `Copy` button!

```
emailID = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mail"]')
emailID.click()
copy_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="click-to-copy"]')
copy_btn.click()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - I run the code, there are no errors but it doesn't print anything out

Answer (score 4):

Your error is occurring b'coz you have imported the module `selenium.webdriver.common.keys`.

You should be using the `Keys` class within that module.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#...

ActionChains.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'c').perform()
```

***EDIT***

It is actually copying the text to the clipboard. You can use a library such as *[pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/)* to get the text.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pyperclip
driver = Chrome('drivers/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://temp-mail.org/en/')
emailID = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mail"]') 
ActionChains = ActionChains(driver)
ActionChains.double_click(emailID).perform()
ActionChains.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'c').perform()
text = pyperclip.paste()
print(text)
```

Output

```
caberisoj@mail-file.net
```

Comment: I have removed selenium.webdriver.common.keys and instead added from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys module - But now i am getting this error: cannot import name 'keys' from 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys

Comment: @XxDanxX It's `Keys` with a capital K

Comment: OMG, thank you so much man! I can't believe a simple thing would cause an error like that, thanks! I am now coming across where it doesn't seem to copying the text -  I run the program, let it copy, then i stop the program and try paste it but it doesn't paste that text

Comment: Thanks. However, I seem to getting an error that says "No module named 'pyperclip'" even though I have imported it

Comment: @XxDanxX You should install pyperclip first. `pip install pyperclip`.

Comment: That works, thanks but it just outputs no module named pyperclip - Like there isn't an error or anything, it just outputs it. I installed pyperclip as a package on Pycharm

Comment: @XxDanxX I do not use PyCharm. It is an error. It just mans that either your installation was not successful or  maybe you need to restart pycharm or maybe you are running the code using a different python interpreter [ideas  from the top of my head]

Comment: no worries, ill make a separate post and see if anyone can help me, thanks for the help!

Comment: Good answer! @XxDanxX make sure you don't have any folders named pyperclip... that can mess up the imports... (In my answer I just used the button `Copy`...)

Answer (score 2):

Never rely on clipboard in your automated tests, it is not safe. The tests must be fully [atomic and independent](https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Best+Practices%3A+Use+Small%2C+Atomic%2C+Autonomous+Tests) and given you store the data in the clipboard it means that you will not be able to [execute your Selenium tests in parallel using i.e. Selenium Grid](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/selenium_distributed_test_execution_environments/)

Also reconsider using your [locator strategy](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies), I would recommend locating elements by [ID](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) where possible as this is the fastest and the most reliable way.

So if you run the following code:

```
driver.get("https://temp-mail.org/en/")
temp_email = driver.find_element_by_id("mail").get_attribute("value")
print(temp_email)
```

you should see the temporary email address value in the terminal.

Comment: correct! using `get_attribute("value")` should work!